# Which measure could tell me about what is the best predictor in survival analysis?

Tags: survival, feature-selection, model-selection, cox-model

I have data of cancer survival, like that:

```
> my.data
survival stage my_class
27       3     2
221      2     1
43       3     3
...
```

The survival is the time of survival since diagnosis in months (for example, in the first line the patient died 27 months before the diagnosis) and stage and my_class are two factors which I use to construct two different survival curves (considered to me as two models: one by stage, and other by my_class).

I want to know which measure should I use to determine which is the best predictor the "stage" or "my_class".

In R fitted the models, like that:

```
> fit.stage <- coxph(Surv(survival) ~ stage, data = my.data)
> fit.my_class <- coxph(Surv(survival) ~ my_class, data = my.data)
```

The summary of these objects include Rsquare and concordace, and I still can extract AIC (with extractAIC from the stats package) and AUC from SurvivalROC:

```
> extractAIC(fit.stage)

> extractAIC(fit.my_class)

> survivalROC(my.data$survival,
    replicate(length(my.data$survival), 1),
    as.numeric(my.data$stage), NULL, 251, method = "KM")

> survivalROC(my.data$survival,
    replicate(length(my.data$survival), 1),
    as.numeric(my.data$my_classifier), NULL, 251, method = "KM")
```

I am newer in the field survival analysis models evaluation, and I am in doubt about which of these measures I should use to select the best model between these two for example. Another predictos or combinations will be involved in the study too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use both predictors? 

AIC (and other similar measures) impose a penalty on fit for the number of parameters. Your two models each have one parameter, so the penalties will be the same.